# Switch Tabs and Reset Nav's View Controllers at the same time-Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, selectedindex

I have a tabBarController with 2 tabs:

tab0, tab1

In tab0 I have a navigationController with 3 child views

viewA (root), viewB, viewC

pressing a button in viewC will bring me to tab1 using code

```
@IBAction func switchButtonTapped(sender: UIButton){
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

The problem I'm having is that once I switch to tab1 I can't get tab0 to reset  back to viewA (its root vc), it stays on viewC.

How do I switch from tab0 to tab1 and at the same time reset the views in tab0?

Since I'm simultaneously switching tabs and resetting a nav controller's vcs should this happen on different threads?

```
 @IBAction func switchButtonTapped(sender: UIButton){
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated:true)
} 
    }
```

Comment: No, it all needs to happen on the main thread as you are doing now. In general what you're trying to do should work. Have you tried changing the `animated` parameter to `false`? You don't really want an animation here.

Comment: @Dima it works both ways. Thanks for the help 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note: Swift 3 Code:*

```
@IBAction func switchButtonTapped(sender: UIButton){
    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

This works fine for me (it selects the second tab and when I tap on the first tab button, It shows the root -first- ViewController for the first tab).

Comment: I show an implementation of this from a different tab as my answer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716918/popping-a-view-controller-in-different-tab/40857974#40857974)  for those looking for that solution.  I use NSNotifications to do the trick so that you can achieve this from anywhere in code.